# Are these all idiomatic phrases regarding turning to a certain age and do they mean the same?

Tags: idiomatic-language, colloquial-language

1. I'll be 18 tomorrow.
2. I'm turning 18 tomorrow.
3. I'll turn 18 tomorrow.
4. I will be turning 18 tomorrow.
5. I'm going to turn 18 tomorrow.

Are these all idiomatic phrases regarding turning to a certain age and do they mean the same?

Comment: 'To turn + age' indeed means 'to reach that number of years in age'. Your question doesn't seem to be about 'turn' though, but about the grammatical forms to describe the future event.

Comment: @JMB that is a good point!